# cfhttp multipart & facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, coldfusion, cfhttp

I'm playing with the facebook graph api, and was attempting to send an image to my wall.  According to facebook, you just send the image, your access key & a caption... see below my code:

```
<cfoutput>
 <cfif fileexists("D:\myPath\images\menubar.jpg")>
  <cfhttp method="post" url="https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos" multipart="yes">   
   <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="access_token" value="myAccessToken">
   <cfhttpparam type="file" name="source" file="D:\myPath\images\menubar.jpg">
   <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="message" value="this is a test picture.">
  </cfhttp>
  <cfdump var="#cfhttp#">
 </cfif>
</cfoutput>
```

When I run this, I get a 400 bad request error ("OauthException an unknown error occurred" returns from facebook).  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?   Thanks!

Comment: I run your code and it works. Check your accessToken. If myAccessToken is a variable then it needs to be "#myAccessToken#".

Comment: myAccessToken is not a variable, I just didn't want to post an actual access token--  I'm filling it in as I receive it-- yes, i know that's completely impractical, but i'm just trying to get a test to run before i get it working sexy.  This does give me hope, though.

Answer (score 1):

can you check your access token format?
usually parameters set as `access_token=somedata&expires=sometimestamp`
At the statement you mentioned above, you have to pass just access token literally. I make it bold here. access_token=**somedata**&expires=sometimestamp

I've been trying to solve the same problem nearly for 3 hours. :) and finally did!

Answer (score 0):

I've run into issues using https when the secure certificate hasn't been imported into the Java/ColdFusion keystore. More info on how to achieve that here:

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/400/kb400977.html

Hope that helps!